# Jarsigner issue with android studio 3.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, jarsigner, android-app-bundle

I am trying to generate a signed Bundle(.aab file) for my app.  
  
I get this error :

> Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
>      
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
>      
> java.lang.RuntimeException: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 :
>      
> jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

I have already a .jks file that I already used to deploy the app the play store.

When I use the key to generate a signed APK (.apk file) it works fine ; (the key is fine and the password is correct).

Comment: All the other instances of such errors I've encountered on Stackoverflow were because the entered password was incorrect. Have you ensured that your task to sign the bundle uses the same signing configuration as the one used to sign the APK? Consider also a project clean.

Comment: @Pierre I use android studio to generate the signed bundle , so nothing manual . Is there a way to look under the hood ? Also I tried cleaning project but with no success

Comment: File a bug with Android Gradle Plugin.